# Flatten recursive data

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table glclassifications (Exact software) that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [glclassifications](
    [ID] [nvarchar](500) NULL, --(contains uniqueidentifier)
    [Code] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Parent] [nvarchar](500) NULL --(contains uniqueidentifier)
)
```

It holds classifications that are hierarchical (hence the Parent column that refers to the ID of another record.)

I need this table to be 'flattened' so that I have

```
Parent_ID, 
Parent_code, 
Parent_description, 
--child1 
Child1_ID, 
Child1_code, 
Child1_description, 
--child2
Child2_ID....
```

-- up until including child9

and so on.

My predecessor left me with this query that violates a lot of the designprinciples that we agreed upon. One of those is not using (temp)tables. I would like to simplify this script and preferably get the output as a  view and not as a table. A catch is that the resulting view needs to deliver columns for 8 children, even if there are less in the table...

```
/* drop duplicates  in glclassifications */
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)
    ) RN
    FROM   [dbo].[glclassifications]
)

DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE  RN > 1;
/* drop tmp table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #H;
CREATE TABLE #H (    
    Code varchar(100),
    Description varchar(250),
    ID varchar(100),
    Division int
)
/* declare table */
DECLARE @n INT = 1
DECLARE @Sql varchar(50)
WHILE @n < 10 BEGIN
    DECLARE @col_name varchar(10) = CONCAT('Code_' , @n) 
    SET @Sql = 'ALTER TABLE #H ADD ' + QUOTENAME(@col_name) + ' varchar(20) NULL'
    EXEC (@Sql)
    SET @col_name = CONCAT('Name_' , @n) 
    SET @Sql = 'ALTER TABLE #H ADD ' + QUOTENAME(@col_name) + ' varchar(250) NULL'
    EXEC (@Sql)
    SET @n = @n + 1 
END
/* insert level 1 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1) 
SELECT 
Code,Description,ID,bip_office,Code,Description 
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications]
WHERE Parent = ''
/* insert level 2 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1, Code_2, Name_2) 
SELECT 
e.Code,e.Description,e.Id,e.bip_office,Code_1,Name_1,e.Code,e.Description
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications] e
JOIN #H h on h.ID = e.Parent 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT ID from #H ) AND Parent IS NOT NULL ;
/* insert level 3 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1, Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3) 
SELECT 
e.Code,e.Description,e.Id,e.bip_office, Code_1,Name_1,Code_2, Name_2,e.Code,e.Description
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications] e
JOIN #H h on h.ID = e.Parent 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT ID from #H ) AND Parent IS NOT NULL ;
/* insert level 4 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1, Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3, Code_4, Name_4) 
SELECT 
e.Code,e.Description,e.Id,e.bip_office, Code_1,Name_1,Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3,e.Code,e.Description
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications] e
JOIN #H h on h.ID = e.Parent 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT ID from #H ) AND Parent IS NOT NULL ;
/* insert level 5 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1, Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3, Code_4, Name_4, Code_5, Name_5) 
SELECT 
e.Code,e.Description,e.Id,e.bip_office,Code_1,Name_1,Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3,Code_4, Name_4,e.Code,e.Description
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications] e
JOIN #H h on h.ID = e.Parent 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT ID from #H ) AND Parent IS NOT NULL ;
/* insert level 6 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1, Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3, Code_4, Name_4, Code_5, Name_5,Code_6, Name_6) 
SELECT 
e.Code,e.Description,e.Id,e.bip_office,Code_1,Name_1,Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3,Code_4, Name_4,Code_5, Name_5,e.Code,e.Description
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications] e
JOIN #H h on h.ID = e.Parent 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT ID from #H ) AND Parent IS NOT NULL ;
/* insert level 7 */
INSERT INTO #H (Code,[Description],ID,Division,Code_1, Name_1, Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3, Code_4, Name_4, Code_5, Name_5,Code_6, Name_6,Code_7, Name_8) 
SELECT 
e.Code,e.Description,e.Id,e.bip_office,Code_1,Name_1,Code_2, Name_2,Code_3, Name_3,Code_4, Name_4,Code_5, Name_5,Code_6, Name_6,e.Code,e.Description
FROM 
[dbo].[glclassifications] e
JOIN #H h on h.ID = e.Parent 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT ID from #H ) AND Parent IS NOT NULL;
/* store to table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[gb-hierarchie];


SELECT hie.*
INTO [dbo].[gb-hierarchie]
FROM #H hie
```

I did this

```
    WITH cte_org AS (
        SELECT       
            ID, 
            Code,
            Description,
            Parent
            
        FROM       
            [dbo].[glclassifications]
        WHERE len(parent) = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            e.ID, 
            e.Code,
            e.Description,
            e.parent
        FROM 
            [dbo].[glclassifications] e
            INNER JOIN cte_org o 
                ON o.ID = e.parent
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte_org;
```

but how to continue?

Comment: If you can be sure you aren't going to have an infinate loop, then use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: If "_the resulting view needs to deliver columns for 8 children_" the simplest answer is probably to `left join` the table 8 times.
A CTE (recursive or not) has a fixed number of columns.

And be careful: `len(parent)` will be `null` rather than `0` if `parent` is null.

Comment: Add `Id as ChildId, 1 as Depth` to the anchor query in your CTE and `, o.ChildId, o.Depth + 1` to the recursive query. That will let you group and order all of the ancestors for each classification. You can query that result adding `, Row_Number() over ( partition by ChildId, order by Depth desc ) as ColumnOrder` to flip the `Depth` values to run from oldest ancestor to child. Then use _conditional aggregation_ and `group by ChildId` to output the rows you want, e.g. `Max( case when ColumnOrder = 1 then Id end ) as ParentId, ..., Max( case when ColumnOrder = 2 then Id end ) as Child1Id, ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Bill Jetzer: simply joining the tables on itself 8 times was the easiest way to get these results